# How to set SVG's(Draw by D3.js) height based on the content?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am using D3.js to draw a tree,same with this chart:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7809166
But the height and width are fixed, I wanna the height can be auto adjust by the content.

My code:

```
var svg = d3.select("#feature_tree").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

If i do not define the height, the tree cannot be showed fully, unless I enlarge the browser, the missing tree nodes can be shown.

If i define the height, e.g. height = 2400px; if the content is very short. there will be a big blank.

Comment: I'd try to set a defined height and a vertical padding for a leaf node in the cluster layout. Then I'd try to multiply that value with the total number of leaf nodes. Theoretically, that would be the final height of the dendogram. Hope will give you a start point.

Comment: Also, you can use [`viewBox` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) to keep your coordinate system constant while changing the size of the SVG via CSS or Javascript outside the SVG/D3 context. With the correct settings, your visualization would scale to fit whatever dimension you throw at the container.

Answer (score 3):

You can measure the height of the content and adjust the SVG element accordingly:

```
var svgEl = document.getElementById("my-svg"),
    bb = svgEl.getBBox();
svgEl.style.height = bb.y + bb.height;
svgEl.style.width = bb.x + bb.width;
```

Simple demo here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpwbKd

Comment: Thanks @Kris for this... One additional comment: if the content of your svg element has a minimum `y` value that is greater than 0, you have to take this into account. The way I solved it was to add an invisible and tiny element at 0,0, then running the getBBox() method for the height.